# How can I put a link to my Xamarin.Android app (in VS2012)?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have done an application by Xamarin Android in Visual Studio 2012. Now I must put a link to my application on the internet. 
How can I do it ?

(if I'm not mistaken, I need to .apk file that I'll be able to put in internet. how to do it ?)

Answer (score 1):

Read the Xamarin Android documentation on [publishing an application](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application).